# How to create a variable in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a little compiler, I want to create a variable in textarea and show it for example.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>test</title>
    </head>
   <body>
     <textarea cols="10" rows="3">
       b = 1
       c = 2
       a = b + c
     </textarea>
     <input type="button" value="send" onClick="comput()">

     <script>
       function comput(){
        //do some think
        return a,b,c;
       }    
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really sure what you'd like to do. Do you want to display the value of a?

Comment: It is not possible. <textarea></textarea> are pure HTML, you cannot create variable into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good idea but you can get the value of the `textarea` & use `eval`

```js
function comput() {
  let val = document.getElementById('txtArea').value;
  let k = eval(val)
  console.log(k)
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="10" rows="3" id='txtArea'>
b = 1
c = 2
a = b + c
    </textarea>
<input type="button" value="send" onClick="comput()">
```

Comment: +1 for the [**not good idea**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!).